# How do I merge an entire branch?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I've recently switched from TFS to Git and have adopted the use of SourceTree to manage what I'm doing. One of the things that I've not managed to work out, is how to merge properly within SourceTree.

I started by selecting my `master` and then hitting the `merge` button in SourceTree. This gives me the following dialog where I can choose just **1** commit.

[image]

What I want to do is merge the entire branch (A,E,L,R,Z,a-z commits). So this threw me - which commit am I supposed to select to do this? If I chose just the last then it shows me one of the changes that I've made, however I've made changes to **2** files through this set of commits:

[image]

What am I missing here? A colleague pointed me to the command line:

`git merge test` seemed to do exactly what I want, but how do I replicate that in SourceTree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to enable the sidebar in order to see the branches list.
Then you just right-click the branch on the sidebar, select 'Merge <branch> into master' and that's it!

[image]